# Professor gets funding and does not give to student

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-process, thesis, funding

I am a recent university graduate with a master's degree, and I secured a position in a sizable company. Interestingly, my master's supervisor is also supervising my sibling's Ph.D.

In a few meetings, I expressed my interest in pursuing a Ph.D. while working, and my supervisor not only supported the idea but also encouraged me to do so. Several months ago, he informed me about an opportunity from a company seeking students for a Mitacs project. He forwarded my CV, along with others, to the company, which eventually selected me based on my background. However, during the orientation, I discovered that the company expected me to relocate permanently to their office without offering any salary, assuming that the university was compensating me. I had raised concerns about the high travel costs, and the professor assured me that he would compensate for it.

During the orientation, it became apparent that the company did not properly value my position, and one of their representatives even questioned my understanding of the company I was working for, despite it being a well-established entity. This raised concerns for me.

Before officially becoming a student, I contacted my professor, who agreed to set up a research assistant role at the university to provide compensation until my student application went through. Everything seemed fine until I unexpectedly received an email from the professor stating that he was resigning me but would retain me for the next significant funding, which would materialize in eight months with the same company.

The following day, during a meeting with the company, they asked for an update. Upon ending the call, they immediately revoked all my accounts, including email and Teams access. After a month and a half, they deleted all my information without considering reimbursement for my high-cost trip and the time invested in the work.

Now, I am contemplating whether bringing up these issues with the professor could jeopardize my sibling's funding and thesis. The entire situation, from the company's unethical behavior to the questionable setup, is both unacceptable and unprofessional.

My question: Could I send an email to the professor and ask for my hours that I put working? Also the trip that was promised to be compensated? How this will affect my sibling's funding?

Please do not advise talking to the lawyer, lawyers are pretty expensive in my country, Canada.

Comment: Note that unpaid internships are illegal in Canada unless you recieve course credit for them

Comment: Hiring lawyers is expensive, but there are a lot of places where it's possible to get a free consultation with a lawyer.

Comment: What is a Mitacs project? Perhaps provide a link?

Comment: I have no link for that

Comment: This is simply to provide a reference for the statement made by @joey-eremondi above ... https://www.canada.ca/en/services/jobs/workplace/federal-labour-standards/interns.html

Answer (score 20):

Your options are probably to either talk to a lawyer (we can't give you legal advice) or cut your losses and move on. Sure, you can ask for funds you're promised but given what you've described that doesn't seem likely to happen without a lawyer's support. Canada no doubt has employment laws that would protect you but only if you assert your rights (which often requires a lawyer).

Don't do any more work for any of these people involved without a signed contract.

If your sibling has a problem, it's that they're working for a shady/flaky professor, not anything created by your own situation. Keep documentation as best you can of what has occurred; if you work with a lawyer they can instruct you on this.

One final note: you say you "secured a position" with a company, but they weren't planning to pay you. I would not describe that as securing anything. It does not sound like there is anything of value for you to try to preserve in this relationship.

A second final note: you say in your title "professor gets funding" but nowhere in your story do I see the professor getting anything. I see a company that thought they could get a free worker and a lot of miscommunication. It's possible there never was any money to pay you with.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing occurring in your own program and work with the university, nor any complaint you make in relation to the events you have described, should have any effect whatsoever on your sibling's PhD candidature.  If it were to do so, that would be a sign of extreme corruption in the university and grounds for serious ethics complaints and reports to the university ombudsman (and possibly also legal action by your sibling).  Indeed, it would be a shocking scandal for a university to retaliate against the sibling of a complainant over a workplace dispute.

As to your own problem and circumstances, it is likely that you have some protections from Canadian employment law.  Typically there are broad protections against "misleading and decptive conduct" in employment as well as specific protections against unfair termination of employment.  It is not clear from your post whether you would be considered to have been an employee of this company, but you certainly put in some time, expense and work, in the expectation of some reciprocal benefit that has not materialised.  If this is something you want to pursue, you could speak to an employment lawyer.